# Function to read data from file knowing what is already read

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to read from a file simulating data is coming from a COM port stream.

The file has 7 column numbers containing samples of a gyroscope and an accelerometer in the XYZ axis, such as:

```
0.02775096893310547 0.0 0.0 0.0 -0.021 0.001 1.018
0.043855905532836914 0.017453292519943295 0.3490658503988659 -3.490658503988659 -0.23800000000000002 -0.165 0.972
0.1978168487548828 0.8377580409572782 0.6283185307179586 -6.789330790257942 -0.28400000000000003 -0.138 0.97
0.29178690910339355 0.10471975511965978 1.2566370614359172 -3.735004599267865 -0.272 -0.168 0.961
0.36679887771606445 0.0 1.3264502315156905 -5.98647933434055 -0.243 -0.20700000000000002 0.967
0.4776029586791992 0.8901179185171081 1.9722220547535925 -9.023352232810684 -0.272 -0.241 0.9430000000000001
```

My approximation consists of two functions:

```
import pandas as pd

myfile = pd.read_csv("bimu_gyro_accel.dat", header=None, delimiter=r"\s+")


def get_the_gyro(row,file=myfile):
    """ Gets XYZ gyroscope axis from 'file' variableName and row number
        Data units is radians
        The result is a dictionary x,y,z keys, e.g., dic['x']
    """
    g_xyz = file.iloc[row-1,1:4]
    g_xyz_dict = g_xyz.to_dict()
    g_xyz_dict['x'] = g_xyz_dict.pop(1)
    g_xyz_dict['y'] = g_xyz_dict.pop(2)
    g_xyz_dict['z'] = g_xyz_dict.pop(3)
    return g_xyz_dict


def get_the_accel(row,file=myfile):
    """ Gets XYZ acceleromenter axis from 'file' variableName and row number
        Data units is 'g, ~9.8m/s^2'
        The result is a dictionary x,y,z keys, e.g., dic['x']
    """
    a_xyz = file.iloc[row-1,4:7]
    a_xyz_dict = a_xyz.to_dict()
    a_xyz_dict['x'] = a_xyz_dict.pop(4)
    a_xyz_dict['y'] = a_xyz_dict.pop(5)
    a_xyz_dict['z'] = a_xyz_dict.pop(6)
    return a_xyz_dict
```

which is a script `read_gyro_accel.py`.

An example of use:

```
>>> from read_gyro_accel import get_the_gyro, get_the_accel
>>> get_the_gyro(3)
{'x': 0.8377580409572782, 'y': 0.6283185307179586, 'z': -6.789330790257942}
>>> get_the_accel(3)
{'x': -0.28400000000000003, 'y': -0.138, 'z': 0.97}
>>>
```

I have to pass the number of the row to get the data. My question is if there is any way to invoke the functions `get_the_gyro` and `get_the_accel` without passing any input parameter and get the next gyroscope and accelerometer XYZ data, and get all row's data in sequence.

Answer (score 0):

do i miss something here?! why you dont declare row as default parameter in your functions. for example: get_the_gyro(row=3, file=myfile). and just callit get_the_gyro() !??

Comment: I have explained it badly. I would like to read all the rows, not just row '3'.

Answer (score 0):

okay now its better explained, we have 3 diffrent aproaches to solve this. 
1. with generators - lazy approach for large files
2. with iterators - i will not give an example
3. with file objects.

first approach (sutable for large files and you want to process the data row by row):

```
def read_gyro_line(file=myfile):
    while True:
        data = file.readline()
        if not data:
            break
        #do some work on data and return the data as dict
        yield data

# below how we call the generator func
with open('file_for_example.txt') as fp:
    for data_line in read_gyro_line(fp):
        do_work_on(data_line)
```

third approach, with python standard file methods. see:

```
def process_data(data_line):
    #do some work on data_line

with open('file_for_example.txt') as fp:
    for line in fp:
        process_data(line)
```

Comment: Thank you, I like these two possible solutions. Still not what I intended to solve. I would like not to iterate in the file with a loop construct. I would like to call the function and get the next line (the first line after the last read) without having to pass and index or iterate. It looks a rare question but is what it would do a function showing the received data from a sensor stream.